# android - RecyclerView item not clickable after drag and drop in Nougat (Android 7.0)

Tags: android

I'm facing this issue only on android Nougat. After drag and dropping an item, the OnClick event doesn't fire on this item anymore.

Here's the adapter :

```
public class VideoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.VideoListViewHolder> implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    private List<Media> videos;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    private int selectedItemPosition;
    private Media selectedMedia;
    private static final int NOTHING_SELECTED = -1;

    public VideoListAdapter(Context context, List<Media> videos, Delegate delegate) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        setVideos(videos);
        this.context = context;
        setSelectedItem(NOTHING_SELECTED);
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int pos) {
        selectedItemPosition = pos;
        if(pos != NOTHING_SELECTED)
            selectedMedia = videos.get(pos);
        else
            selectedMedia = null;
    }

    public void setVideos(List<Media> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
        setSelectedItem(NOTHING_SELECTED);
    }

    private void onVideosReordered() {
        if(selectedMedia != null)
            setSelectedItem(videos.indexOf(selectedMedia));
    }

    public void unselectAll() {
        setSelectedItem(NOTHING_SELECTED);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_video_list, parent, false);
        return new VideoListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String imagePath = videos.get(position).getFilePath();

        boolean isEmptyItem = imagePath == null || imagePath.isEmpty();

        if (isEmptyItem) {
            holder.video_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.img_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

            UtilsMedia.loadThumbnailImageNoSpinAnimation(holder.img_image, imagePath);

            boolean isSelected = selectedItemPosition == position;
            if (isSelected && !isEmptyItem)
                holder.video_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                holder.video_list_item_selected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {

        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++)
                Collections.swap(videos, i, i + 1);
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--)
                Collections.swap(videos, i, i - 1);
        }

        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDropped() {
        onVideosReordered();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class VideoListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        public ImageView img_image;
        public ImageView video_list_item_selected;
        public FrameLayout fl_root;
        public Context context;
        public boolean isSelected;

        private static final String TAG = "VideoListViewHolder";

        public VideoListViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            img_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_image);
            video_list_item_selected = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_list_item_selected);
            fl_root = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fl_root);
            context = view.getContext();
            isSelected = false;

            fl_root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int currentPosition = getAdapterPosition();

                    if (selectedItemPosition == currentPosition) {
                        setSelectedItem(NOTHING_SELECTED);
                    } else {
                        if (selectedItemPosition != -1)
                            notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition);
                        setSelectedItem(currentPosition);

                    }

                    notifyItemChanged(currentPosition);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            final Animation zoomOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_out);
            zoomOut.setDuration(300);
            fl_root.startAnimation(zoomOut);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            final Animation zoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_in);
            zoomIn.setDuration(300);
            fl_root.startAnimation(zoomIn);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the item touch helper callback :

```
public class ItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {
    public static final float ALPHA_FULL = 1.0f;

    protected final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;

    public ItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        final int swipeFlags = 0;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    private int moveSource = -1;
    private int moveTarget = -1;

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) 
            return false;

        if(moveSource == -1)
            moveSource = source.getAdapterPosition();

        moveTarget = target.getAdapterPosition();

        mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemSelected();
        }
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        viewHolder.itemView.setAlpha(ALPHA_FULL);
        if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
        }

        if(moveSource != -1 && moveTarget != -1 && moveSource != moveTarget) 
            mAdapter.onItemDropped();

        moveSource = moveTarget = -1;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove every notifyDataSet changed and replace them by other notifyXXX (notifyItemRangeInserted, notifyItemRangeRemoved, notifyItemRangeChanged, etc)